# How to reset pagination (data-table material) after using filter

Tags: angular, filter, datatable, angular-material, pagination

My project is setup in Angular 12 and Spring Boot (back-end).

I show a list of movies using data-table material with sort and pagination.

I add a filter to this list and when I write any thing I lost my pagination.

Clearly the problem is when I filter with any key I lost my pagination and I can't to see next page.

**-- Response from spring :**
[Response from back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJrqa.png) | [Link response JSONEditor](https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.34556a48789f494db705ccfe661cce25)

**-- Front code :**

*Service*

```
getAll(page: number, size: number): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get<any>(API_URLS.MOVIES_URL, { params: { page, size } });
}
```

*Component*

```
ELEMENT_DATA: Movie[] = [];
isLoading = false;
totalRows = 0;
pageSize = 10;
currentPage = 0;
totalElements = 0;

displayedColumns: string[] = ['titleType', 'primaryTitle', 'startYear', 'genres'];
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Movie> = new MatTableDataSource();

@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator!: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort!: MatSort;

filter = new FormControl();

constructor(private service: MoviesService) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loadData();
}

loadData() {
  this.isLoading = true;

  this.service.getAll(this.currentPage, this.pageSize).subscribe({
    next: cardPage => {
      this.dataSource.data = cardPage.content
      this.totalElements = cardPage.totalElements
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.paginator.pageIndex = this.currentPage;
        this.paginator.length = this.totalElements;
      });
      this.isLoading = false;
    }, error: error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  });
}

pageChanged(event: PageEvent) {
  console.log({ event });
  this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
  this.currentPage = event.pageIndex;
  this.loadData();
}

public doFilter() {
  this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
}
```

*HTML Page*

```
<div class="example-header">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [formControl]="filter" (keyup)="doFilter()" placeholder="Filter">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-progress-bar>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="titleType">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Type </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.titleType}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="primaryTitle">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Titre Premiére </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.primaryTitle}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator #paginator 
        [length]="totalRows"
        [pageIndex]="currentPage" 
        [pageSize]="pageSize"
        [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 100]" 
        (page)="pageChanged($event)">
    </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**Execution :**
[Execution of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuWXy.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this complete example will help you to resolve your issue. Even though the backend is .net you can refer to the angular app for your issue.

https://github.com/erandika1986/Angular_Material_Server_Side_Pagination

Thanks,
Erandika

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will use it defenely.